# Extraction of 'hidden' periodicity in 2d array using np.fft.fft2

Tags: numpy, filter, fft

I need to handle a lot of 2d numpy arrays like the one below
[Color plot of 2d array in work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWl8F.png).
Eye can capture periodical pattern beneath yellow dots. However, applying np.fft.fft2 to this array gives [Color plot of 2d array after 2d FFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPjJD.png).
One could imagine that above-mentioned periodical pattern should give some bright areas after FFT. But it seems like the 'yellow dots' spoiled the FFT completely and the color plot of FFT-transformed array doesn't look informative. Give me some suggestions please how I can deal with this problem? Is it possible maybe to pre-work 2d array, filtering 'yellow dots' beforehand?

I tried myself to cut an array using some cutoff values, but this also worked not good and this solution would be not universal (for my purposes I need to work out automatically a lot of arrays like that).

Comment: There is exactly one pixel in the FFT, at (0,0), that goes all the way up the max value of the color map. The rest are much, much lower values, and therefore all look yellowish in the plot. Adjust the limits to see more of your data, or ideally plot `log(abs(fft(…))+1` or something like that to see the fainter peaks.

Comment: Ok, thank you, will certainly try this

Comment: I tried and result became much better, thanks!
However, the dominant contribution in my FFT is still some non-informative (as I think) values at corners of the picture. Maybe you know the procedure how to extract the periodicity of stripes in this case?

Comment: The DFT is symmetric, the low frequencies are shown in the four corners of the result. If it's helpful to you, apply `fftshift` to move the DC component (the pixel at (0,0) representing a frequency of 0) to the middle of the image. Your pattern should show a peak a little to the right of the center, and its symmetric copy a little to the left of center. But of course there will be other features caused by the remainder of the content of the input image.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I get exactly what I wanted!